# Is there a name for the art style in Gankutsuou?

Tags: anime-production, gankutsuou

In Gankutsuou, the art style is pretty weird. Instead of having normal coloring/shading, different pieces (such as hair or a shirt) have their own pattern that doesn't move with the piece. You can see it in the Count's hair and in the shirt below. Is there a name for this type of art, and is this something that is unique to Gankutsuou or to anime?

[image]

Comment: this style is similar to what's in the ~what a Beautiful ~ Visual Novel Series, in [Sekien no Inganock ~What a Beautiful People~](http://vndb.org/v417/chars#chars) Gii's clothes has the same pattern as what overlaps his eye when his Crack Equation is used, in [Shikkoku no Sharnoth ~What a Beautiful Tomorrow~](http://vndb.org/v1027/chars#chars) a lot of the time i can see a Coat of Arms such as in Mary's Umbrella. difference is that most of the time the character's are not animated

Comment: This type of cell shading is actually used a lot these days, but just not so densely or in such a clashing way.

Comment: I'm not sure what this is actually called, but TVTropes calls it "[Unmoving Plaid](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/UnmovingPlaid)". As @JonLin says, it's used a lot; you can see some pretty egregious examples in Shaft shows.

Comment: "Unmoving plaid" is not a style, it's a side effect of texturing.

Comment: I think this style is inspired from "multiple exposure photography", some anime use a kind of tapestry to render character's clothes and the character moves but this background stays in place.

Answer (score 5):

According to [an interview](http://www.yozone.fr/spip.php?article1798) (in French) with the series creator series creator, Mahiro Maeda, the art style of the anime combines western Impressionism with Ukiyo-e, a 19th century Japanese woodblock printed art style that strongly influenced the Impressionism movement around the same time.

One of the particularly notable mini-movements within impressional is the [Art Nouveau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Art_Nouveau) style, particularly the influence from the Austrian artist [Gustav Klimt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gustav_Klimt), likely best known for his work *The Kiss*. Klimt was mentioned to be one of Maeda's most favorite artists and his works gave way to [inspire the blocks of strong primary colors](https://www.manga-news.com/index.php/actus/2018/03/21/Interview-de-Mahiro-Maeda-fondateur-du-studio-Gonzo) seen in the series.

Klimt's style applies a tension of naturalism and stylization, bridged together by turns through fairly intricate multiform and multi-patterned surfaces and bold contrasts of color with highlights of gold, silver, coral, and gems. This is all wrapped around a pervasively mystical and alluring aura brought about the the spiraling and intertwining lines juxtaposed with stark square and triangular shapes. All of this is reminiscent of a ghostly mosaic aesthetic.

For more information on the visual style, I recommend picking up the illustration art book on the series *Gankutsuou: The Count of Monte Cristo Complete*.

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be a technical name for this animation style. TVTropes calls it [Unmoving Plaid](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/UnmovingPlaid), while it's also referred to as "plaid animation" and "static pattern animation".

Outside of animation, this is also lumped in with, for example, a pattern such as plaid or polka dots not changing orientation on a shirt as the character moves. This shows up in manga and comics as a way to avoid having to reorient a pattern every time the character moves.